# How to access civicrm_subscription_history in Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'd like to extract contacts who have been added to a certain group for a given date or date range. This information is in table civicrm_subscription_history which is included in my Drupal settings file, along with every other CiviCRM table.  But this table doesn't appear in Views - it seems that only a selection of CiviCRM tables appear, and I don't understand why this is. How can I access this table in Views? (I know this is perhaps more of a Views question but hopefully it's also enough of a CiviCRM question!) Using Civi 5.24.5 & Drupal 7.69

Answer (score 2):

[Views CiviCRM Expose Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_civicrm_expose_tables) might work for you.